# How can i use an SDK in Visual studio with c#?

Tags: c#

Recently I approaced C# and I've tried to see some projects, but I still don't understand how exactly I can use an SDK. Is it a ready to go project? When i download it I just need to modify some items in the SDK to create any kind of project or do i need to create a new file and somehow use the SDK? How can I use it?

Comment: Using nuget package manager? or add Assembly?

Comment: Ok, but how can i use the SDK funtionalities with Nuget or by adding Assembly?

Comment: A software development kit may contain just about anything that help with development. In .net the unit for reusable components is an assembly (i.e. .dll file), these are often distributed thru nuget, since this takes care of dependencies and other problems. So how you use some particular SDK depend on what it contains and how it is distributed. But there is not enough details in the question to give any specific advice.

Answer (score 2):

To install the Visual Studio SDK after completing your Visual Studio installation, rerun the Visual Studio installer and select the Visual Studio extension development workload.